# Given $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, which of these does not necessarily exist as a finite real number?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

We have $f(x) > 0, \forall x \in \mathbb R$ $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$

Which of these, if any, does not necessarily exist as a finite real number?

$$1. \lim_{x \to a} |f(x) - f(a)|$$
$$2. \lim_{x \to a} e^{f(x)}$$
$$3. \lim_{x \to a} \sqrt{f(x)}$$
$$4. \lim_{x \to a} \ln(f(x))$$
$$5. \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}$$

I think we have this other condition that $f(x)$ is continuous. I'm fairly certain $f(x)$ is not given to be differentiable.

So 1 and 2 seem to exist as for the others...

Comment: From the information given the function is continuous at $a.$  It is not given that the function is continuous or bounded away from $a.$  The other postential sticker... even though $f(x) >0$ for all $x, \lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)$ can equal $0.$  e.g. consider $y=x^2$ as $x$ goes to $0.$

Comment: @DougM Right so 1 and 2 are okay. As for 3, $L \ge 0$. So it's either 4 or 5. For 5 we just make a substitution (see answer below please)...?

Comment: @DougM How is $f$ continuous at $x=a$? What's the problem if it isn't?

Comment: 1) is a problem as we don't know if $f(x)$ is bounded for all $x.$  2) is okay. 3) is okay.  4) is a problem if $L=0.$  5) is okay because the limit exists even if $f(x) = 0$

Comment: @DougM 1 - So what if it's not bounded? $$\lim_{x \to a} |x^2 - a^2| \ \text{exists...?}$$ 5 - You mean 'even if $\color{red}{L}=0$'?'

Comment: 1)sorry I thought 1) said $|f(x)- f(a)|$ and not $\lim_\limits {x\to a} |f(x) - f(a)|$ 4) is a problem if $L=0$ it is not a problem when $L>0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...

3. exists because $L \ge 0$
4. may not exist if $L=0$
5. seems like may not exist if $L=0$ and $f(x)$ is not differentiable if we try to use L'Hospital's rule such as with $f(x) = |x|$ and $L=0$

but it exists simply because

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)} = \lim_{u \to L=0}\frac{\sin u}{u} = 1$$